# How can I change the icon of a button in android gridView row?

Tags: android

I want to change the button of android grid view row item, when I click in the first row, I can change the button (play) to (pause),  then when I go to another row, also I can change the play to pause, but I need to change the previous row automatically to pause, because it is now still play.

I have tried the code below but not effect.

**Main Grid XML**

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:numColumns="1"
    android:horizontalSpacing="16dp"
    android:verticalSpacing="16dp"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:clipToPadding="false"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Row XML**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewMain"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/img4" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewMain"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageViewMain"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageViewMain"
        android:text="PRİNCESS BİRTHDAY"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="24dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewYazar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#412204"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:text="Yazar : "
        android:layout_below="@+id/textViewMain"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textViewMain"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textViewMain" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewYazarName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Yazar adı"
        android:textColor="#412204"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textViewMain"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textViewYazar"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textViewYazar"
        android:layout_marginLeft="26dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewSeslendiren"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#412204"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:text="Seslendiren : "
        android:layout_below="@+id/textViewYazar"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textViewMain"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textViewMain" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewSeslendirenName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Seslendiren Adı"
        android:textColor="#412204"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textViewYazarName"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textViewYazar"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textViewYazarName"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewSizeDuration"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#412204"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:text="120 MB / 130 Mins"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textViewSeslendirenName"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textViewMain"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textViewMain" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonPlay"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/imageViewBottomLine"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textViewMain"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_action_play"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewTL"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/tl_simgesi"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textViewPrice"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textViewPrice"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewPrice"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="2.70"
        android:textColor="#E85404"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/imageViewBottomLine"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonAdd"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_action_basket_dark"
        android:layout_above="@+id/imageViewBottomLine"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:onClick="onAddToCard"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewBottomLine"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageViewMain"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/top_line" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**View Adaptor GetView Code**

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    final ViewHolder holder;
    LayoutInflater inflator = activity.getLayoutInflater();
    imageLoader = new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());

    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.gridrow2, null);
        holder.imgViewMain = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewMain);
        holder.txtViewTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewMain);
        holder.txtViewPrice = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewPrice);
        holder.txtViewCast = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewSeslendirenName);
        holder.txtViewAuthor = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewYazarName);
        holder.txtViewSizeDuration = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewSizeDuration);

        holder.play = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.buttonPlay);
        holder.addcart = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.buttonAdd);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    imageLoader.DisplayImage(urlList.get(position), holder.imgViewMain);
    if (title.get(position).length() > 30) {
        holder.txtViewTitle.setTextSize(20);
    }
    holder.txtViewTitle.setText(title.get(position));
    holder.txtViewPrice.setText(price.get(position).replaceAll(" TL", ""));
    holder.txtViewCast.setText(cast.get(position));
    holder.txtViewAuthor.setText(author.get(position));
    holder.txtViewSizeDuration.setText(size.get(position) + " / " + duration.get(position));

    holder.imgViewMain.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent in = new Intent(activity.getApplicationContext(), SubMenu.class);
            in.putExtra("Title", title.get(position));
            in.putExtra("Id", id.get(position));
            in.putExtra("Author", author.get(position));
            in.putExtra("Description", description.get(position));
            in.putExtra("Img", urlList.get(position));
            in.putExtra("Price", price.get(position));
            in.putExtra("Size", size.get(position));
            in.putExtra("Duration", duration.get(position));
            in.putExtra("Publication", publication.get(position));
            in.putExtra("Cast", cast.get(position));
            activity.startActivity(in);
        }
    });
    holder.play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (holder.click == 0) {
                stopPlayer(v.getContext(), position, previousPosition);
                productId = id.get(position);
                PlayExecute(v.getContext());
                v.setBackground(v.getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_pause));
                holder.click = 1;
                previousPosition = position;
            } else {
                stopPlayer(v.getContext(), position, previousPosition);
                v.setBackground(v.getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_play));
                holder.click = 0;
            }
        }
    });

    holder.addcart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            v.setBackground(v.getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_basket));
            prfs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(activity);
            productId = id.get(position);
            AddExecute();
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}
```

StopPlayer and change previous icon

```
public void stopPlayer(Context c, int current, int previous) {
    System.out.println("current : " + current);
    System.out.println("previous : " + previous);

    if (mp != null && mp.isPlaying()) {
        mp.stop();
    }

    if (current!=previous){

        View v= this.getView(previousPosition, null, null);
        Button b = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.buttonPlay);
        b.setBackground(c.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_play));
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
        mGridview.refreshDrawableState();
    }
}
```

see the attached image please;
http://postimg.org/image/b3fbpc211/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think of you question as a `partial refresh` one. We all run into `partial refresh problem` when dealing with `ListView` or `GridView`. As for your case, `partial refresh` may be like this:

```
private void refreshPartially(int position){
    int firstVisiblePosition = listview.getFirstVisiblePosition();
    int lastVisiblePosition = listview.getLastVisiblePosition();
    if(position>=firstVisiblePosition && position<=lastVisiblePosition){
        View view = listview.getChildAt(position - firstVisiblePosition);
        if(view.getTag() instanceof ViewHolder){
            ViewHolder vh = (ViewHolder)view.getTag();
            //holder.play.setBackgroundResource(resId);//Do something here.
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing this

```
View v= this.getView(previousPosition, null, null);
```

change your drawable on item click method

```
mGridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                 Button b = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonPlay);
        b.setBackground(c.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_play));
        your_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
```

I think , this will work for you :)